# How to define Similarity Rules?

Tags: pattern-matching, alignment, sequence

I have a question about *Mathematica*'s `SimilarityRules` defining (for e.g. `SequenceAlignment` function). So help centre clearly stands for

> `SimilarityRules -> {{a_, a_} -> 1, {a_, b_} -> -1}`, giving a score of `+1` for any pair of identical elements, and a score of `-1` for any mismatch, deletion or insertion.

Ok, I get it, but what if I want to give different score for mismatch, and different for indeles? I tried:

```
SimilarityRules -> {{a_, a_} -> 3, {{a_, b_} && {{a_!=""} && {b_ != ""}}} -> -8}
```

and many other combination of `{}`, `&&` positions, but it doesn't seem to help. Any suggestions, is it just a typo I'm doing, or it's rather a silly idea to define it like this?

Comment: You could add a test case (with desired output) to make the question more comprehensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [/;](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html)

For instance: `SimilarityRules -> {{a_, a_} -> 
   3, {a_ /; a != "", b_ /; b != ""} -> -8}`

Comment: ditto the request for an example. I cant cook up anything where this produces a different result from the default.

Comment: ! EXACTLY. Thank you so, so much, that's what I needed, Condition (/;) thing, I've never used it in Mathematica before